# Create individual files by matching records in one array with a unique list of names in another array in Perl

Tags: arrays, file, perl, unique, matching

I have two files:

File 1 contains a unique list of names and File 2 contained a list of names with additional data.

Note: File 2 can have multiple records for the same name.

For example:

File 1:

```
ARRON LYNCH
PATRICK MOLONEY
JAMIE MOTT
MICHELLE PAYNE
DANIEL STACKHOUSE
JORDAN CHILDS
LUKE NOLEN
... etc.
```

File 2:

```
ARRON LYNCH,WANGARATTA,RACE 1,BILLIEO (1),MARK STEPHENSON,C,1
PATRICK MOLONEY,WANGARATTA,RACE 1,DALLAS COWGIRL (2),BRENT STANLEY,CC,1
JAMIE MOTT,WANGARATTA,RACE 1,FREE FLYING STAR (3),JOHN MCARDLE,BBB,1
JAMES WINKS,WANGARATTA,RACE 2,AMERICAN WHISKEY (1),MICHAEL, WAYNE & JOHN HAWKES,BBB,2
TEODORE NUGENT,WANGARATTA,RACE 2,MATSUMOTO (2),MITCHELL BEER,CC,2
ALEXANDRA BRYAN,WANGARATTA,RACE 2,O'REG (3),ALLAN FITZGERALD,C,2
LUKE NOLEN,WANGARATTA,RACE 3,ALKAAMEL (1),DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG,BBB,3
BILLY EGAN,WANGARATTA,RACE 3,CRUNCHIE (4),PATRICK PAYNE,AA,3
CAMPBELL RAWILLER,WANGARATTA,RACE 3,DANCING DUCK (5),RUSSELL OSBORNE,B,3
TEODORE NUGENT,WANGARATTA,RACE 4,DARCY EKCELS (1),RICHARD LAMING,A,4
BRAD RAWILLER,WANGARATTA,RACE 4,LOVE HURTS (3),RICKY MAUND,BBB,4
LUKE NOLEN,WANGARATTA,RACE 4,MESSAGE (4),JOHN MOLONEY,CC,4
JARROD FRY,WANGARATTA,RACE 5,DEFINIA (1),GWENDA JOHNSTONE,B,5
CLAYTON DOUGLAS,WANGARATTA,RACE 5,CHINA AFFAIR (2),JASON WARREN,A,5
DYLAN DUNN,WANGARATTA,RACE 5,AYTON (4),DAVID & BEN HAYES & TOM DABERNIG,BBB,5
TEODORE NUGENT,WANGARATTA,RACE 6,WIND FORCE (3),BEN BRISBOURNE,CCC,6
MADISON LLOYD,WANGARATTA,RACE 6,CARWELKIN (4),MARK THOMAS,CCC,6
ARRON LYNCH,WANGARATTA,RACE 6,DEVIL'S RAIN (5),MARK C. WEBB,B,6
DYLAN DUNN,WANGARATTA,RACE 7,TATUNKA (1),R F DONAT,AAA,7
JACK HILL,WANGARATTA,RACE 7,CAMPOBASSO (2),ROBERT HICKMOTT,AA,7
ARRON LYNCH,WANGARATTA,RACE 7,COONAWARRA (3),MARK C. WEBB,BBB,7
... etc.
```

Note: ARRON LYNCH appears 3 times in File 2.

I've been able to successfully load both File 1 and File 2 into arrays in order to produce File 3 (see code below).

File 3:

```
ARRON LYNCH,WANGARATTA,RACE 1,BILLIEO (1),MARK STEPHENSON,C,1
ARRON LYNCH,WANGARATTA,RACE 6,DEVIL'S RAIN (5),MARK C. WEBB,B,6
ARRON LYNCH,WANGARATTA,RACE 7,COONAWARRA (3),MARK C. WEBB,BBB,7
PATRICK MOLONEY,WANGARATTA,RACE 1,DALLAS COWGIRL (2),BRENT STANLEY,CC,1
PATRICK MOLONEY,WANGARATTA,RACE 5,BEL'S BANNER (5),UDYTA CLARKE,A,5
PATRICK MOLONEY,WANGARATTA,RACE 6,BEAUTY BETTY (7),LEON & TROY CORSTENS,AAA,6
PATRICK MOLONEY,WANGARATTA,RACE 7,GREEN IVY (4),KEN KEYS,CCC,7
JAMIE MOTT,WANGARATTA,RACE 1,FREE FLYING STAR (3),JOHN MCARDLE,BBB,1
JAMIE MOTT,WANGARATTA,RACE 2,INSIDE EDGE (8),JOHN MCARDLE,A,2
JAMIE MOTT,WANGARATTA,RACE 4,BORONDINO DREAM (13E),TRENT BUSUTTIN & NATALIE YOUNG,BB,4
JAMIE MOTT,WANGARATTA,RACE 6,MECKLENBERG COUNTY (11),CINDY ALDERSON,BB,6
MICHELLE PAYNE,WANGARATTA,RACE 1,LA MARSA (4),MICHELLE PAYNE,CCC,1
DANIEL STACKHOUSE,WANGARATTA,RACE 1,LUNARES (5),MATHEW ELLERTON & SIMON ZAHRA,B,1
DANIEL STACKHOUSE,WANGARATTA,RACE 2,BON SHADOW (14),GWENDA JOHNSTONE,BB,2
DANIEL STACKHOUSE,WANGARATTA,RACE 2,SETTLE THE SCORE (18),JOHN & CHRIS LEDGER,B,2
DANIEL STACKHOUSE,WANGARATTA,RACE 4,MRS WHITTEN (10),CINDY ALDERSON,BB,4
... etc.
```

Note: ARRON LYNCH correctly appears 3 times in File 3, PATRICK MOLONEY correctly appears 4 times, and so on..

Here is the working code:

```
# Input File (File 1: Unique List)
my $unique_jockeys_file = "UNIQUE-LIST-OF-JOCKEYS-RIDING-TODAY.list";
open (INFILE, "<$unique_jockeys_file") or die "Could not open $unique_jockeys_file $!";
foreach(<INFILE>)
{ 
    push @ri_list, $_ unless ($_ eq "\n"); 
} 
close INFILE;

# Input File (File 2: All Jockeys Rides Today)
my $jockey_rides_file = "JOCKEY-RIDES-TODAY.list";
open (INFILE, "<$jockey_rides_file") or die "Could not open $jockey_rides_file $!";
foreach(<INFILE>)
{ 
    push @lin, $_ unless ($_ eq "\n"); 
} 
close INFILE;

# Output File (File 3)
my $jockey_rides_match_file = "JOCKEY-RIDES-TODAY-MATCHED.list";
open (OUTFILE, ">$jockey_rides_match_file");
foreach $ri (@ri_list)
{ 
    chomp $ri; 
    for (@lin) 
    { 
        if ($_ =~ /$ri/ ) 
        { 
            print OUTFILE $_; 
        } 
    } 
} 
close OUTFILE;
```

I'd also like to produce a separate file for each name containing the matched records for each name. For example; 3 matched records for ARRON LYNCH (i.e. ARRONLYNCH.txt), 4 matched records for PATRICK MOLONEY (i.e. PATRICKMOLONEY.txt), and so on.

This is my code at the moment. Unfortunately, I cannot see why it's not working.

```
foreach $ri (@ri_list) # Input File (Unique List of Jockeys Riding Today)
{ 
    chomp $ri;
    for (@lin) # Input File (All Jockeys Rides Today)
    { 
        $line = $_;
        chomp($line);

        my ($jockey, $racecourse, $racenum, $hnameandnum, $trainer, $TDRating, $PRO) = split(/,/, $line);

        $outfile = "$jockey.jocknumrides";        

        open (OUTFILE, ">$outfile");

        if ($jockey =~ /$ri/ )
        { 
            print OUTFILE "$jockey, $racecourse, $racenum, $hnameandnum, $trainer, $TDRating, $PRO\n";
            print "$jockey, $racecourse, $racenum, $hnameandnum, $trainer, $TDRating, $PRO\n";
        }
        close OUTFILE;
    } 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are overwriting the output file with every iteration of the inner loop. Changing from `>` to `>>` in your `open` statement might help, provided that the output files are not present to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible way to printout the names to separate files, one per jockey.

It stores the data from file2 in a hash `%data` keyed by the jockey's name.

Then for every name from the jockey names file, file1, you check whether it exists in the file with all the information and if so, open the file for writing and write in the data for that jockey.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature 'say';

my %data;

my $file2 = 'f2.txt';
open my $fh, "<", $file2 or die "$file2: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    next unless length;
    my $jockey = (split/,/, $_, 2)[0];

    push @{ $data{$jockey} }, $_;
}

close $fh or die $!;
# print Dumper \%data;

my $file1 = 'f1.txt';
open $fh, "<", $file1 or die "$file1: $!";

while (my $jockey = <$fh>) {
    chomp $jockey;
    if (exists $data{$jockey}) {
        my $outfile = "$jockey.jocknumrides";
        open my $output, '>', $outfile or die $!;

        for my $line (@{ $data{$jockey} }) {
            say $output $line;  
        }
        close $output or die $!;
    }
}

close $fh or die $!;
```

Comment: Superb! Very clean & it does exactly what I need it to do. Well done. Thank you very much @ChrisCharley Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Please see if following demo code complies with your requirements.

The approach to process data slightly different from your code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $fname_jockeys = 'UNIQUE-LIST-OF-JOCKEYS-RIDING-TODAY.list';
my $fname_rides   = 'JOCKEY-RIDES-TODAY.list';
my $fname_matched = 'JOCKEY-RIDES-TODAY-MATCHED.list';
my $fname_rider   = 'JOCKEY-RIDES-TODAY-';

my $list_jockeys = read_jockeys($fname_jockeys);
my $list_rides   = read_rides($fname_rides);

save_matched_rides($fname_matched,$list_jockeys,$list_rides);
save_individual_riders($fname_rider,$list_jockeys,$list_rides);

sub save_individual_riders {
    my $fname_prefix = shift;
    my $list_jockeys = shift;
    my $list_rides   = shift;

    my @fields = qw/jockey racecourse racenum hnameandnum trainer TDRating PRO/;

    for my $jockey ( sort @$list_jockeys ) {
        my $fname = $fname_prefix . uc $jockey . '.list';
        open my $fh, '>:encoding(utf8)', $fname
            or die "Couldn't to open $fname";

        for my $ride ( @{$list_rides->{$jockey}} ) {
            say $fh join(',',@$ride{@fields});
        }

        close $fh;
    }
}

sub save_matched_rides {
    my $fname        = shift;
    my $list_jockeys = shift;
    my $list_rides   = shift;

    my @fields = qw/jockey racecourse racenum hnameandnum trainer TDRating PRO/;

    open my $fh, '>:encoding(utf8)', $fname
        or die "Coudn't to open $fname";

    for my $jockey ( sort @$list_jockeys ) {
        for my $ride ( @{$list_rides->{$jockey}} ) {
            say $fh join(',',@$ride{@fields});
        }
    }
    close $fh;
}

sub read_rides {
    my $fname = shift;

    my %rides = ();
    my @fields = qw/jockey racecourse racenum hnameandnum trainer TDRating PRO/;

    open my $fh, '<:encoding(utf8)', $fname
        or die "Couldn't to open $fname";

    while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        chomp $line;
        next if $line =~ /^\s*$/;
        my %ride;
        @ride{@fields} = split(',', $line);
        push @{$rides{$ride{jockey}}}, \%ride;
    }

    close $fh;

    return \%rides;
}

sub read_jockeys {
    my $fname = shift;

    my @data;

    open my $fh, '<:encoding(utf8)', $fname
        or die "Couldn't to open $fname";

    while( <$fh> ) {
        chomp;
        next if /^\s*$/;
        push @data, $_;
    }

    close $fh;

    return \@data;
}
```

Comment: Hey @PolarBear This demo code most definitely complies with my requirements. I must say, this is a beautiful piece of coding by you. Well done! I may frame it and hang it on the wall in my office. ;-) Thank you very much for your effort here. I knew there was a better way to do what I needed. Cheers & all the best!